# How Do I Make somthing a Character in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, character

I know how to move a character using arrow keys, but how do I signal which image I want the character to be

Here is my code on making it move on arrow keys, but how do I mark that an image is the character?

```js
///// store key codes and currently pressed ones
var keys = {};
    keys.LEFT = 37;
    keys.RIGHT = 39;

///// store reference to character's position and element
var character = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  element: document.getElementById("character")
};

///// key detection (better to use addEventListener, but this will do)
document.body.onkeyup = 
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
  var kc = e.keyCode || e.which;
  keys[kc] = e.type == 'keydown';
};

///// character movement update
var moveCharacter = function(dx, dy){
  character.x += dx||0;
  character.y += dy||0;
  character.element.style.left = character.x + 'px';
  character.element.style.top = character.y + 'px';
};

///// character control
var detectCharacterMovement = function(){
  if ( keys[keys.LEFT] ) {
    moveCharacter(-1);
  }
  if ( keys[keys.RIGHT] ) {
    moveCharacter(1);
  }
};

///// game loop
setInterval(function(){
  detectCharacterMovement();
}, 1000/24);
```

If you can help thanks! (: I am new to Javascript.

Comment: `document.getElementById("character")` <- change that line and you are done

Comment: what do you mean by "image is a character" ? do you want to replace the character with an image and move it around with arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this. Add a image of your character in the body of your page and give it id="character" . Also use initial CSS like in the below snippet

```js
///// store key codes and currently pressed ones
var keys = {};
    keys.LEFT = 37;
    keys.RIGHT = 39;

///// store reference to character's position and element
var character = {
  x: 100,
  y: 10,
  element: document.getElementById("character")
};

///// key detection (better to use addEventListener, but this will do)
document.body.onkeyup = 
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
   
  var kc = e.keyCode || e.which;
  keys[kc] = e.type == 'keydown';
};

///// character movement update
var moveCharacter = function(dx, dy){
  character.x += dx||0;
  character.y += dy||0;
  character.element.style.left = character.x + 'px';
  character.element.style.top = character.y + 'px';
};

///// character control
var detectCharacterMovement = function(){
  if ( keys[keys.LEFT] ) {
    moveCharacter(-1);
  }
  if ( keys[keys.RIGHT] ) {
    moveCharacter(1);
  }
};

///// game loop
setInterval(function(){
  detectCharacterMovement();
}, 1000/24);
```

```css
#character{
  position:absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 10px;
}
.wrap{
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<body>
<span>Click on Mario and use LEFT/RIGHT arrows to move it</span>
<div class="wrap">
<img src="https://rocketdock.com/images/screenshots/Mario-Icon.jpg" id="character"/>
</div>
</body>
```